# Enable follow-mode for PDF in doc-view/pdf-view-mode

Tags: docview, follow-mode

Is it possible to customize follow mode to open the next PDF page in another buffer? Currently `follow-mode` has no effect on PDF files.

Comment: I believe this would be a new feature that someone needs to invent.

Comment: One approach would be to extend `follow-mode` so that modes like `doc-view` would be called at appropriate times to fill the windows with appropriate content.

Answer (score 5):

This feature does not yet seem to exist. I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools/issues/74) requesting this feature on `pdf-tools` git.

Comment: I have made this a community wiki so that people knowledgeable about this topic can collaborate to an awesome solution.

Comment: I would love to participate on this! Unfortunately, I'm extremely time limited, but I can provide is some insight into the internals of `follow-mode`, as I'm the author of it.